# How can i fix this error? [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data')],

Tags: api, react-native

Here's my code in my tab.js, please help #beginner, i am trying to get the data from the server using API, but i don't know how to fix the error that always pop up.

[Here's a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLaQO.jpg)
Error:
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data')]

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to execute the function `await listingApi.getListing()`?